# Glide Library decode format

Tags: android, gif, transparent, android-glide

I want the glide library [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to use the ARGB_8888 decode format so that i can get a better picture quality but i don't really know where exactly to change that setting.This page [Glide Config](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) sheds some light on it but i am still unsure of its exact use.I need to use it for default square images and not circle images.My current code looks like this.

```
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(custom.getImage_path())
                    .override(width, height / 2)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(vh4.getImage_path());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it's pretty simple,the answer is on this page [Glide Information](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)  along with a lot of other useful information about the library.